# How to adapt a Markdown template/Latex Package to R-Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, rstudio, pandoc

Lately I've been writing a great deal of assignments using R Markdown. It's incredibly helpful and saves me a lot of hassle.

The issue comes when, as I'm from Brazil, some assignments must follow a specific set of norms commonly called ABNT. I've searched for templates to use those norms, but nothing specific for R Markdown appeared.

I've found two resources that may help my situation: [this Markdown template called Limarka](https://github.com/abntex/limarka/) and [this Latex package that I've already used on Overleaf some time ago.](https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt) They do not have any specific documentations regarding usage on R Markdown, so I've decided to try and take matters into my own hands.

I tried to put the .tex templates in the /templates folder or into the project folder as well and referring to the template in the YAML, but they do not seem as they should. I think there's a much more simpler solution to this, but I've only recently began to mess around with R Markdown. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the quick comment, but I remember using `{rticles}` package and sweave files to begin blending Latex and R.

Comment: No problem! I'll try to mess with the archives and see if I can do something with the rticles files, thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you see [this chapter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html) from the R Markdown book?